# negative and positive clarification in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the product table.

```
product_name | quantity
------------   --------
IPhone       |        5
IPhone       |        5
IPhone       |       10
Nokia        |       -9
Nokia        |       -8
Nokia        |       25
Samsung      |       -2
Samsung      |        2
Samsung      |       20
```

I need to form the SQL query when the quantity is positive for all records for a particular product. In this example required output is.

```
Iphone
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME
HAVING MIN(QUANITY) >= 0;
```

It is classic example of learning `GROUP BY` Clause. You group all the data using the product name, and to look for any negative quantity just, try to take a `MIN()` of it, which is called a aggregate(group) function.

In order to filter the grouped data, we have to use `HAVING` clause, rather than using a `WHERE` clause. because, `WHERE` filters even before the data is grouped. whereas `HAVING` filters only after the grouping is done.